# Laravel reports "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." when I change the order of the routes

Tags: laravel

I created the two routes and if I use them in the order

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
```

Laravel reports "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." But if I change the order to

```
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
```

it works as expected. Why is the first ordering not working?

Comment: Shoudn't be a problem with order, then also please try to clear cache and try again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `posts/{post}` will handle all requests to `/posts/*` including `/posts/create`:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
Route::get('posts/create', 'PostsController@create');
```

So, you need to define `create` and similar routes before the `posts/{post}` route.

Answer (score 1):

Because the routing mechanism will only try routes until one of them matches the request, then it stops.

if you have the request "`Kill Mark`" and you have this list:

```
Kill all of the mankind
Kill Mark
```

(all of the mankind dies, Mark included)

but if you have this other list

```
Kill Mark
Kill all of the mankind
```

(only Mark dies)

Comment: I like how you explained (y) :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe the routes are matched in order

So if you hit this URL: post/create

```
Route::get("post/{post}", PostsController@show);

Route::get("post/create", PostsController@create);
```

The first route will be hit, and therefore will try to show a post that doesn't exist (i.e. a post with an ID of "create")

So reordering them does fix this. However, if you used more RESTful routes, it would help avoid this issue:

```
Route::get("post/{post}", PostsController@show);

Route::post("post", PostsController@create);

Route::patch("post/{post}", PostsController@update);
```

Etc...

This way, the verb more indicates the way which the route should behave